# Idiomatic way to define constant functions

Tags: purescript

Disclaimer: I'm new to purescript and have yet to grok the amazing but somewhat overwhelming type system.

Say I want a function which ignores its argument and always returns the same value. Defining this manually as an anonymous function is not a problem:

```
(\_ -> 42) <$> [true, false]
-- => [42, 42]
```

But I wondered whether there's a more idiomatic (and concise) way of doing this. [Data.Const](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-const/0.5.0/docs/Data.Const) might be involved, but I have yet to figure out how to use it for this. Something like `(getConst 42) <$> [true, false]` does not work.

*edit*: Defining this myself:

```
makeConst :: forall a b. a -> (b -> a)
makeConst x = (\_ -> x)

(makeConst 42) <$> [true, false]
-- => [42, 42]
```

This works fine, but I wouldn't be surprised if something like that exists in the standard modules and I simply didn't see it...

Comment: I think you want the const function: `(const 42) <$> [true, false]`

Comment: Yup, that's it. Guess I should have read the Prelude functions before posting this. Mind making this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: FYI in your specific example of `const 42 <$> [true, false]` there are the `<$` and `$>` combinators from `Data.Functor` in purescript-control.  Used as such: `42 <$ [true, false]` and `[true, false] $> 42`.  Reference: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-control/0.3.2/docs/Data.Functor#v:(<$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`const`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/0.1.4/docs/Prelude#v:const) function

```
const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
```

which you can use to create your function:

```
(const 42) <$> [true, false]
```